# Making dynamic content forms with checkbox

Tags: crafter-cms

How do I make my content forms dynamic in CRAFTER CMS?

I want my form to hide/unhide other form controls when a checkbox is checked.

I also want to require certain fields (form controls) to be filled out when a checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: You can use the code as mentioned in w3schools - [tryhow_js_display_checkbox_text](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_display_checkbox_text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form engine doesn't currently have any pre-built relationships/interactions between form controls.  That said, form controls are just simple javascript that you can create/add or extend.

Here is a link to a short guide on creating custom form controls: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/developers/extending-studio/form-engine-control.html